# Where Can I Find This Report Of Sayyidah Aisha (Radhi'allahu'anha) In Sahih Ibn Hibban?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

The author Muhammad Salih Al-Munajjid at Islamqa.info in Fatwa # 3801 has stated the following:-

Al-Bukhaari reported in his Saheeh (no. 250) that ‘Aa’ishah said: “The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)and I used to bathe from one vessel.”

Al-Haafiz said in al-Fath: “Al-Daawoodi interpreted this to mean that it is permissible for a man to look at his wife’s ‘awrah and vice-versa. **This is supported by the report narrated by Ibn Hibbaan via Sulaymaan ibn Moosa, who was asked about a man looking at his wife’s private parts. He said: ‘I asked ‘Aa’ishah, and she referred to this hadeeth.’ This is evidence in this matter.** And Allaah knows best.” [Source:- https://islamqa.info/en/answers/3801/husband-and-wife-taking-a-bath-together-and-looking-at-one-anothers-private-parts]

**My main question is: where can I find Sulayman ibn Musa's narration in Sahih Ibn Hibban where he stated that Aisha (Radhi'allahu'anha) referred to the hadith in Bukhari when she was asked about whether a man could look at the private parts of her wife? Can someone please point out the narration in Sahih Ibn Hibban?**

Comment: https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/8234#p1

Comment: @UmH - I am a person who studies Hadith and narration. Please pardon me for asking about pointing out narrations as I am not a native Arabic speaker. So I need to ask someone to point out them for me. I hope you can understand. Thanks.